# Ruby on Rails Routing Error uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby, exception

am new whit ruby, have this exception 
Routing Error
uninitialized constant
i do everything that in this forum said , but dosent work

this is my db

```
class CreateCredits < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change

create_table :credits do |t|

  t.string :type

  t.float :amaunt

  t.date :creditdate

  t.date :expiredate

  t.decimal :rake

  t.string :waranty


  t.timestamps
end   end end
```

this mi controller class  is defined like this:

```
class CreditsController < ApplicationController


  # GET /credits


 # GET /credits.json

def index
@credits = Credit.all

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @credits }
   end
end

 # GET /credits/1
 # GET /credits/1.json
 def show
   @credit = Credit.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @credit }
   end
end

  # GET /credits/new
 # GET /credits/new.json
 def new
   @credit = Credit.new

   respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @credit }
 end
end

# GET /credits/1/edit
def edit
  @credit = Credit.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /credits
 # POST /credits.json
 def create
  @credit = Credit.new(params[:credit])

respond_to do |format|
  if @credit.save
    format.html { redirect_to @credit, notice: 'Credit was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @credit, status: :created, location: @credit }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @credit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end

  # PUT /credits/1
  # PUT /credits/1.json
 def update
@credit = Credit.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @credit.update_attributes(params[:credit])
    format.html { redirect_to @credit, notice: 'Credit was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @credit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
   end

    # DELETE /credits/1
  # DELETE /credits/1.json
  def destroy
@credit = Credit.find(params[:id])
@credit.destroy

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to credits_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
  end
end
```

and this is my route 
Defining this route as a scope instead of a namespace, didn't work aswell.

```
 Insolvencia::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :Credit
  get "credit" => "credit#index"
  root :to => 'credit#index'
   match "credit", :to => "credit#index"
 end
```

Comment: please provide the exact error message so we can actually help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `resources :credits` instead of `resources :Credit`